# Error raised during calls in asterisk server

Tags: asterisk

Today my asterisk could not receive calls for a while. when I checked the asterisk logs, the error below was raising during this period.

```
Purely numeric hostname (1002), and not a peer--rejecting!
```

After I restarted the asterisk the problem solved. **What is the problem?**

Comment: For a question like this, you may be able to get more help on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asterisk

Comment: I don't know why vote to close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Very likly that mean your dns server was not working. Use local dns caching server or more then one dns server.

Other posible situation - you calling somethign like SIP/1234, which is not in your sip.conf.

Here is related source part, it have description:

> peer = sip_find_peer(peername, NULL, TRUE, FINDPEERS, FALSE, 0);
>
> ```
>     if (peer) {
>             int res;
>             if (newdialog) {
>                     set_socket_transport(&dialog->socket, 0);
>             }
>             res = create_addr_from_peer(dialog, peer);
>             dialog->relatedpeer = sip_ref_peer(peer, "create_addr: setting dialog's relatedpeer pointer");
>             sip_unref_peer(peer, "create_addr: unref peer from sip_find_peer hashtab lookup");
>             return res;
>     } else if (ast_check_digits(peername)) {
>             /* Although an IPv4 hostname *could* be represented as a 32-bit integer, it is uncommon and
>              * it makes dialing SIP/${EXTEN} for a peer that isn't defined resolve to an IP that is
>              * almost certainly not intended. It is much better to just reject purely numeric hostnames */
>             ast_log(LOG_WARNING, "Purely numeric hostname (%s), and not a peer--rejecting!\n", peername);
>             return -1;
>     } else {
> ```

Comment: My Dns Server is Microsoft Dns Server. So Why when I restarted the asterisk the problem solved?

Comment: Is it also related to this error -->Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Unknown)

Comment: How i can know? maybe you use realtime and was no connection to db or something like that. I just can check in code and give you most likly variants. Next time when you have such situation, you need check it BEFORE restarting.